# Importing existing Python SAV File into Environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am trying to import a .sav file (a predictive model generated in python), but am not making much progress. I've used [this tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.readsav.html), but it still has not helped. `models/` is the directory where the .sav file is located. Any help would be appreciated.

```
sc.io.readsav('models/Predictive_Model.sav', idict = 'model')
```

Error:

```
    724     signature = _read_bytes(f, 2)
    725     if signature != b'SR':
--> 726         raise Exception("Invalid SIGNATURE: %s" % signature)
    727 
    728     # Next, the record format, which is '\x00\x04' for normal .sav

Exception: Invalid SIGNATURE: b'\x80\x03'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pickle to save the model:

```
# save the model to disk
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))

# some time later...

# load the model from disk
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.score(X_test, Y_test)
print(result)
```